# Codenameone How to change Picker Text color

Tags: java, kotlin, codenameone

Picker has two components :

1. The **Initial/Selected value displayed in Codenameone UI**.
2. The **Native picker** dialogs/sheets.

It makes sense that we can not control the `theme/color/style` of **Native Pickers** as they are influenced by an **OS-specific theme** selected by the user.

**But** how do we change the color of text inside the picker in Codenameone Interface? 
What I want to do in the following screenshot is to make the texts "`3/20/20,       00:00,      & 0-5 persons`" white.

What I tried :

1. Channing the "Label" font-family in CSS changed the font so I tried changing the "color" from CSS but it didn't help.
2. I tried changing the foreground color like this : `timePicker.style.fgColor = 0xfffff`
3. In CSS I defined a style.

   ```
    DropdownStyle{
       background-color: #333333;
       color: #FFFFFF;
   }
   ```

   Then I set the style to picker

   ```
   datePicker.uiid ="DropdownStyle"
   ```

But none of the above ways worked as expected.

What is the right way to do it? I believe I am missing a very simple thing but I couldn't find it myself.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's the `Picker` UIID which you need to customize in the selected, unselected and pressed states.
Notice that when you run in lightweight mode the picker UI is drawn by us and is 100% cross platform

Comment: Picker{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
} . This didn't work, in face its the other way around..

Comment: But did you customize the `.selected`, `.pressed`, `.disabled` selectors?

Comment: Yeah I tried all of these :  Picker.selected {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
}
Picker.pressed {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
}
Picker.disabled {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
}

But it didn't work either

Comment: Just so we are clear, we're talking about the square picker button and not the scroll-able chooser UI that pops up afterwards. That isn't customizable as it's often implemented natively.

Comment: Yeah I understand that scrollable part is not customizable, the issue is with the value displaying text/square/button/label

Comment: Did you look in the component inspector? Did you try playing with the value there and seeing the impact or lack thereof?

Answer (score 0):

AS @shai-almog suggested, after digging through **Component Inspector**, I found out that

[image]

- A `PickerComponent` has the ID `"TextComponent"` so if we replace the `UIID` of `PickerComponent` it's going to change the style of just the **Holder Component** **that's why I was able to change the background-color only but not the text**.
- Inside it, there is `Picker` which Represents the **Text** and has the id `TextComponentField`.

So I had to Style them individually like this :

```
    TextComponent{
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);

    }
    TextComponentField{
        color: white;
    }
```

Output :

[image]